# My SQL returned empty result set, what's the solution?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0000 seconds.)

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
```

Comment: Uhm... how about adding a user?

Comment: It simply means you don't have any record in your table `users`

Comment: First you insert one record in `users` table then execute `select` query

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your table is empty, just insert rows into your table and then repeat select query again. Here a sample of insert query (for case when your `user` table consists of two fields - name and email)

```
INSERT INTO `users` (name, email) VALUES ('Abram', 'abram@noemail.com');

SELECT * FROM `users`;
```

Comment: I am signing in for a test but then it doesn't add a user to the table and results an empty result set.

Comment: just use your column names instead of (name, email). This insert query works perfectly for specified table.

Comment: $u_check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$un'");                                                                                         Is there any mistake in coding?

Comment: Seems SQL is ok. But mysql_query returns resource on success, so you should execute, for example, mysql_fetch_assoc for resolving username. More info you can find here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php